# modify cp to copy to current directory if nothing else is specified

Tags: linux, unix, cp

Can I modify `cp` so that it copies to the current directory if I don't specify a destination?

I want this command `$ cp ../launcher.sh .` to be equivalent to `$ cp ../launcher.sh`. Is this modification possible?

Edit

Here is my best attempt so far. When I call the funciton something other than `cp` it works...

```
function cp() {
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    cp $1 $2
else
    cp $1 .
fi
}
```

Comment: write your own sh script and then alias it to cp?

Comment: That sounds perfect!

Comment: if this helps you you can answer your own question. Them others with the same problem can find your solution

Comment: I actually don't know how to write a bash `cp` function

Comment: you don't have to rewrite cp but just funnel all parameters to the existing cp function. Check weather you only have one path parameter and if so, call cp with $1 and execution path

Comment: @JonasDralle I edited my question to show my attempt at doing that. It works when I call the function `cpp` but not when I call the function `cp` (I think that creates a recursive definition)...

Comment: If you had used `/bin/cp` instead of `cp` in the function body, then I think it would have worked. I already alias `cp`, but I tested a similar function with `mv` and `/bin/mv`, and that was OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like:-

```
CP() { [ $# == 1 ] && cp "$@" . || cp "$@"; }
alias cp=CP
```

These can be added to `~/.bashrc` if you want a semi-permanent change.

Note that an alias will not work in a script: if you need a change which will work in scripts, after verifying the location of the real `cp` first, you can use a private `$HOME/bin` directory at the head of your `$PATH` list and in it create an executable script `cp` containing:-

```
/bin/bash
[ $# == 1 ] && /bin/cp "$@" . || /bin/cp "$@"
```

You will need to add `export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH` to `~/.bashrc`

Note also that any options before the first file will invalidate the test for a single parameter. You will need to scan the parameters in the function to check for parameters not beginning with `-`, stopping the test at `--`, and then make sure there is only one parameter left.